# Waiting for a subset of threads in a Java ThreadPool

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool

Let's say I have a thread pool containing `X` items, and a given task employs `Y` of these items (where `Y` is much smaller than `X`).

I want to wait for all of the threads of a given task (`Y` items) to finish, not the entire thread pool.

If the thread pool's `execute()` method returned a reference to the employed thread I could simply `join()` to each of these `Y` threads, but it doesn't.

Does anyone know of an elegant way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `execute()`ing `Runnable`s, just [`invokeAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) some `Callable`s - then you get a `Future` for each on which you can call `get()`, which blocks until the task is finished.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a CyclicBarrier and have each thread wait only when it is of type Y.  For example.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(X.size);

public void executeAllAndAwaitCompletion(List<? extends Y> myRunnableY){
   final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(myRunnable.size()+1);
   for(final Y y : myRunnableY){
       executor.submit(new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
                y.run();//for the sake of this example y has a run method
                barrier.await();
           }
       }); 
    }
   barrier.await();
}
```

So each thread that is running type Y will wait until all those Y's have completed.  Note you have to add 1 to the barrier size to account for the initially executing thread to wait also.

Also Note: If Michael Borgwardt's example works for you that would be best.  However, if you need the thread pool, for each thread that is running Y to not run any other non-Y's then my solution would be the only way you can do it.  Future.get() will only block the calling thread, and when the thread pool finishes Y's execution it will then pick up some other (possibly non-Y) task.

Comment: That's really cool - thanks - but all of the tasks are of the same type (they just belong to different parents).

Comment: Oh I see, you can still use that mechanism accordingly, you would just have the parent y's have a reference to the cyclic barrier and they can then await on it accordingly.  Otherwise you know a different way of synchronizing :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `CompletionService` which is used for exactly this purpose.

- Create `Executor`
- Create `ExecutorCompletionService` using the Executor
- Submit tasks via the `CompletionService`
- Use `take` or `poll` on the CompletionService to wait for the tasks to finish
- Repeat until all the tasks you submitted have finished
- Done

You can share an Executor with something else, just create the `CompletionService` over the top and use it for your specific tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Create `CountDownLatch` with `Y` as count and do `latch.countDown()` in each of `Y` tasks. In the end `latch.await()` will ensure that all of the `Y` tasks are completed.